# How to populate drop-down list with two database column in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp

i want to display user first_name, middle_name, last_name in the dropdown. i have added get function in modal/entity/user.php file. But i am getting "Record not found in table "users".

Here is the code

```
//controller 
$this->loadModel('Users');
$us  = $this->Users->find('list',
                         ['keyField' => 'id',
                          'valueField' => function ($Users) {
                             return $this->Users->get('label');
                          },
                          'conditions' => ['user_role in (3,5)', 
                                           'status' => '1']]); 
$this->set('us', $us);
```

//ctp file

```
echo $this->Form->input('driver_id', ['options' => $us, 'empty'=>'Select Driver', 'class'=> 'form-control']);
```

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP!

Comment: That being said, you should access the `$Users` argument, not the `$this->Users` property, that's two very different things, the former is an entity, the latter is a table class, hence the error.